# compare filename to an integer

Tags: java, mysql

I have a database in `mysql` with field `userId, userName etc,.` from here I'm retrieving `userid` based on some criteria.

I have a folder with files and name of the file is some `userId` . I want to compare retrieved `userId` with those files and if they match further process those files.

I tried this code but its giving number format exception. not able to understand why?

```
package read;

 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.sql.*;
 public class read1 {
 static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
 static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
 static final String USER = "root";
 static final String PASS = "root";
 public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try{

  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
  System.out.println("Creating statement...");
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  String sql;
  sql = "SELECT userId FROM profile1 where friendCount >200 AND statusCount > 200";
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
  processing p = new processing();
    File directory = new File("/home/abc/tweet");

    //get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

    while(rs.next()){
     int uid = rs.getInt("userId");
     System.out.print("ID: " + uid +"\n");
      for (File file : fList){
        if(file.isFile())
        System.out.println(file.getName());
        if(Integer.parseInt(file.getName())== uid)
        p.process(file.getName());    

                 }
            }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
}

class processing{

    void process(String filename)throws Exception{
     FileReader fr = new FileReader("/home/abc/tweet/"+filename);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

      FileWriter wr = new FileWriter("/home/abc/newtweet/"+filename);
                String s;
                    String str="Text:";
                    String a[];
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(wr);
                while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                         if (s.startsWith("Text:"))  { // worked
                         a= s.split(" ");
                         for(int k=1;k<a.length;k++)
                           bw.write(a[k]+"\n");          //   worked

                        }
                     }
                    br.close();
                   bw.close();

    } 
  }
```

Comment: Please add the entire exception (including call stack) to your post.

Comment: ^ also highlight the line no. causing exception
...

Comment: My best guess is that this is the offending line: `if(Integer.parseInt(file.getName())== uid)`. You may want to surround it with `try-catch` block to trap [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) and skip such file names (if this is what you want).

Comment: this is the exception,there is no file as 876 but still its showing.Connecting to database...
Creating statement...
ID: 100008949
876~
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "876~"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at read.read1.main(read1.java:60)
Java Result: 1

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be that there are also other files in the folder `/home/abc/tweet/` with names that cant be parsed as an `Integer`.